# Find all limit points in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Find all limit point in $(\mathbb{R}^3,d_2)$ ($d_2$ denotes the distance by the eucledian norm) of $\{x_n=(x_n^1,x_n^2,x_n^3)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by

${x_n^1}=0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2...$

${x_n^2}=0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4...$

${x_n^3}=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6...$

How would I approach this?

Comment: My guess would be that every point is a limit point since the sequence is repeated every $3*5*7=105$ time, but Im sure if I can conclude it

Comment: This sequence is periodic, so its limit points are precisely the members of the sequence.

Comment: That was my thoughts too, but it just doesn't seem very strict. How would one show it mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy to see that every member of a periodic sequence is a limit point of the sequence. I'll prove the converse in more generality because I think the notation will be easier. Suppose our sequence is periodic with period $n$, so it goes $$ x_1, x_2 , \ldots x_n, x_1, x_2 , \ldots x_n, x_1, \ldots $$
Let $a_n$ be a subsequence of our sequence. If $a_n$ is (eventually) constant, then it has limit point equal to that value, which is a member of the sequence.

Otherwise it is not eventually constant, by the pigeon-hole principle there is a term $x_i$ which appears infinitely often. As the subsequence is not eventually constant, infinitely often $a_n \neq x_i$, and so again by pigeons there is a term $x_j \neq x_i$ which appears infinitely often in $a_n$. Consequently $a_n$ has a subsequence which is constantly $x_j$ and another which is constantly $x_i$. As $x_i\neq x_j$ then $a_n$ does not converge.

Therefore the only convergent subsequences of the thing we started with, are eventually constant, and so the only limit points of the sequence are the terms that repeat infinitely.

---

Notes: This holds in more generality that stated above.

It works for any sequence build out of finitely many terms (we don't need it to be periodic). Also, the only fact about metrics spaces used was that if $a_n$ is a sequence with subsequences converging to different points then the sequence does not converge. This is true in any Hausdorff space: A space in which you can separate distinct points by open sets.